# How to fetch the history messages in gerrit via REST API

Tags: gerrit

[image]

How to fetch all the messages in the history section(messages in the image attached) via REST API of Gerrit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't get what you want, just the inline comments left in the review.

For example:

```
curl -user USER:PASS --request GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/comments | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[][] | {Updated: .updated, Message: .message}"
```

Returns:

```
{
  "Updated": "2021-03-03 12:58:18.000000000",
  "Message": "MESSAGE-1"
}
{
  "Updated": "2021-03-03 14:13:44.000000000",
  "Message": "MESSAGE-2"
}
{
  "Updated": "2021-03-03 14:23:05.000000000",
  "Message": "MESSAGE-3"
}
```